# How to share photo from Imageview to WhatsApp?

Tags: java, android, share

I have some photos in drawable and view all one by one in ImageView 
by create 3 buttons

- next
- back
- Share Image

now I want to share photo that in ImageView to whatsapp .
I want to share directly without saving it.

I tried to implement this but it sent some time file to whatsapp

so I deleted my code and needed help.

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Button bt_next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
    final Button bt_back = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_back);

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int R = rnd.nextInt(6);

    imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("s".concat(String.valueOf(R)),"drawable",getPackageName()));


    bt_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (photo_number <6){
                photo_number ++;
                imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("s".concat(String.valueOf(photo_number)),"drawable",getPackageName()));
                bt_back.setEnabled(true);

            }else
            {
                bt_next.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });
    bt_back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (photo_number >1){
                photo_number --;
                imageView.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier("s".concat(String.valueOf(photo_number)),"drawable",getPackageName()));
                bt_next.setEnabled(true);

            }else
            {
                bt_back.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
    });


}

public void btn_share (View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(String.format("android.resource://" + getPackageName() +  R.id.imageView ));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INDEX, uri);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "share photo");

    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, "مشاركة الصورة");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
       startActivity(chooser);
 }


}




}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if WhatsApp can handle that type of URI, but you're missing a `/` between that package name and the resource ID. Also, are you sure `Intent.EXTRA_INDEX` would be the right key for that?

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52129608/how-to-share-image-from-link-i-e-without-downloading-the-image-just-share-usin

Comment: thank you ,my problem is fixed ,i see code in some site it work with me in facebook and whatts app ,